# Ubuntu Login Loop and LibGL error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login

After installing a Nvidia GeForce GTX 770 graphics card I tried to install Nvidia's proprietary drivers via the "Additional drivers" dialogue.

After rebooting the computer the login screen appeared but I was not able to login. The screen turns black for a second then it falls back to the login screen.

So much about what happened - these are my specs and what I have tried so far:

System: Ubuntu 15.10
Added the Graphics Drivers PPA to the software sources, tried all available drivers listed in the additional drivers dialogue leading to the same result. The only driver that works well is the Nouveau one.
Then I checked whether there is a .Xauthority problem - but there is none.

However in `~/.xsessions-error` these error messages appear:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

same here. solved it by reinstalling the proprietary driver from nvidia with the xxx.run driver from nvidia homepage. then performe an init 3 , executing the xxx.run file as root and now the important thing to install the additional 32bit lib etc. reboot and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

When i installed my Nvidia driver i had to turn off secure boot from my UEFI settings. Ubuntu would login after i did that.